# Moved to a new private server and now having troubles uploading large files through PHP

Tags: php, apache, upload

I have a shared server and have been able to upload files approx. 50 megs in size with no problems and have set limits in my php.ini file to allow uploads up to 100 megs.

I took the dive and got a private server account and have changed my php.ini file to match the one on my shared box... now for some reason I can not upload files around 50 megs.

The items I changed in php.ini for testing purposes included:

```
memory_limit: 200M
max_execution_time: 1000
max_input_time: 1000
upload_max_filesize: 100M
post_max_size: 200M
--*These are just set like this for testing purposes until I get it working...*
```

Additionally, I've set an .htaccess file in both the directory of the script that is executing after the upload and the destination folder that contains:

```
"LimitRequestBody 102400000"
```

Yet still it isn't working. I guess I'm just confused why this would work on a shared box but not my new VPS. Is there a setting I'm missing somewhere?

I've previously tested a 40 meg file and it worked but 43 megs did not...

More specifically it seems I am getting an error running this in the php script that handles the file:

```
!is_uploaded_file($_FILES['photoupload']['tmp_name']){
echo "error";
}
```

which leads me to believe it has something to do with http post but, I can't be positive on that and the identical script, as I said, works perfectly on the shared server.

Could it have something to do with the apache user's permissions?  I'm pretty stumped at this point.

Any assistance is appreciated!

Comment: Use `phpinfo()` to check if the settings from your ini file are really being applied.

Comment: Check out [this](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php) link and see what error is shown in your case

Comment: FAngel, I did that and got an "UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE
Value: 7; Failed to write file to disk. Introduced in PHP 5.1.0."

Which is weird because I can upload other files so I wouldn't think it's permissions.

Comment: Also, I checked the amount of available space in my /tmp/ folder and it is 111M...

Comment: you must place `@` before user name, like `@Ron` if you want that user to be notified. Question author will be notified without name specified

Comment: Ah, thanks for that @FAngel .  So any ideas based on the error?

Comment: Have you checked phpinfo()? Does it show numbers you set or no? Is /tmp/ a path where uploaded files are stored? also - 111M of space looks somehow small. Possibly you should try to increase it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked to make sure you have a temp directory set in place and configured properly?

I would suspect you are fine there if that 40 MB upload was to this new server.

I would compare your PHP settings through the phpinfo() call between the 2 servers to find what you are missing.  Apache won't have anything to do with it if your posting it through the PHP.

Comment: I did check my temp (/tmp/) and it says I have 111M available.  The php.ini files are identical.

Answer (score 0):

If your server is in a data center, it's possible the data center is throttling your transfer speeds downward to the point it takes longer than 15 minutes to upload a 50 meg file. If your apache config and server is setup the exact same way, it signals a networking issue. Trying increasing max_input_time: 1000

Comment: I currently have it set at 1000 and it's taking about 5 mins to upload.